# Why Cannot i connect to Docker postgres, running in my machine?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

[image]left is my docker-compose.yml and right that my docker is up and still I cannot access the database.

Can you tell me how can I alternately connect to the postgres database in docker (remember I am using Windows 11 OS)

```
  version: '3.8'
services:
  dev-db :
    image : postgres:13
    ports : 
      - "5434"
    environment : 
      POSTGRES_USER : postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD : eresto
      POSTGRES_DB : eresto
    networks :
      - 4s
networks:
  4s:
C:\Users\srika\TestPrograms\E-Resto\e-resto-api>npx prisma migrate dev
```

Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "eresto", schema "public" at "localhost:5434"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5434`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5434`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at ports "5432:5432" worked for me.

What the concept is, to expose the localhost server and put the ports in string.

Answer (score 1):

You have not exposed the database on your host machine.

Please set the ports like this in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  dev-db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      # Exposed on 5434 - but Postgres internally
      # lives on port 5432 (that is the default)
      - 5434:5432
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=eresto
      - POSTGRES_DB=eresto
    networks:
      - 4s

networks:
  4s:
```

Comment: No, I tried this, this is not working

Comment: I have just updated my answer. The Postgres instance runs internally on port 5432, but should be exposed on port 5434 on your host machine.